# Are the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a vector bundle the only obstructions to its being invertible?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology

Consider vector bundles on connected paracompact topological spaces. Such a vector bundle $E$ on $X$ is said to be invertible if there exists some other bundle $F$ whose sum with $E$ is trivial: $E\oplus F \simeq \epsilon ^N $. The terminology "invertible" (used by Tammo tom Dieck for example) comes from K-theory and is not so weird as it looks:in $\tilde K(X)$ the class of $F$ is indeed the additive inverse of that of $E$. If all vector bundles on $X$ are invertible, then every class (=virtual bundle) in $\tilde K(X)$ is represented by an actual bundle, which is rather nice.

Now, every vector bundle is invertible if $X$ is compact or is a differentiable manifold or even a topological manifold or even a subspace of some $\mathbb R^n$ or even a space of finite combinatorial Lebesgue dimension or even ...  [Please correct me if I'm wrong: this is an interpretation/synthesis of what I read, sometimes between the lines, in several places.]

So one might optimistically hope that every vector bundle on a paracompact connected space is invertible: after all, what could go wrong? Here is what.

Consider $X=\mathbb {RP}^{\infty}$ (infinite dimensional real projective space) and the tautological line bundle  $\gamma$ on $X$. Its total Stiefel-Whitney class is 
$w(\gamma)=1+x \in H^\ast (\mathbb {RP}^{\infty},\mathbb Z /2)=(\mathbb Z /2)[x]$, where $x$ is the first Stiefel-Whitney class of $\gamma$ . If  $\gamma$ had an inverse vector bundle $F$  we would have $w(\gamma) w(F)=1$ and this is impossibl since $w(\gamma)=1+x$ is not invertible in the cohomology ring  $H^\ast (\mathbb {RP}^{\infty},\mathbb Z /2)=(\mathbb Z /2)[x]$ ( a polynomial ring in one indeterminate over $\mathbb Z /2)$.

This leads me to ask the question:

**If a vector bundle on a connected paracompact space has a total Stiefel-Whitney class invertible in its cohomology ring, does it follow that the bundle itself is invertible?**

Comment: Minor comment: the cohomology ring of RP^\infty should really be thought of as a power series ring, not a polynomial ring, so 1 + x _is_ invertible.  The problem is that its inverse has infinite degree so you can't get a _finite_ dimensional bundle as the inverse.  It does, however, have an infinite dimensional inverse: L^\perp.  However, once you allow infinite dimensional inverses, _everything_ has an inverse as E + H = H where H is a Hilbert space.  (mumble, mumble, numerable cover, mumble, mumble, contractibility of unitary group, mumble, mumble)

Comment: Dear Andrew, you are right but I knew this ( although I am not quite sure about the fourth mumble...). I am intersted in finite rank bundles exclusively.

Comment: I suspected that you might, which is why I left it as a comment.

Comment: I don't like the notation "invertible bundle", because it clashes with "invertible sheaf" in algebraic geometry (which is not a sheaf whose -reduced?- Grothendieck group additive inverse has a "genuine" representative). I would call such objects "complementable" bundles instead. 

Comment: I agree that "invertible" is not an ideal terminology, but again it is  used in tom Dieck's new book Algebraic Topology, which may very well become,along with Hatcher's magnificent homonymous tome, *the* standard textbook in the field. A variant terminology I have seen in Osborn is "stably invertible". As an algebraic geometer I am quite aware of the terminology "invertible sheaf","invertible module",... used in a mutiplicative sense: that's why I spelled out the definition I had in mind. And, last but not least, I like your terminology "complementable" and wish it good luck!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is no.  Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ not divisible by $2$, let $V$ be an irreducible $2$-dimensional representation of $G$, and consider the associated vector bundle $EG\times_G V\to BG$ (which I'll call $V$ again).  Then $V$ has trivial Stiefel-Whitney classes since $H^q(BG;\mathbb{Z}/2)=0$ if $q>0$, but $V$ can have non-vanishing Pontryagin class (we have $H^*(BG;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(nx)$ where $x\in H^2$, and $p(V)=1-a^2x^2$ with $a\in \mathbb{Z}/n$ depending on the original representation.)  Since the Pontryagin class satisfies Whitney sum up to $2$-torsion, this gives a counterexample: the virtual bundle $-V$ is does not come from a vector bundle, since $p(-V)=(1-a^2x^2)^{-1}$.

Now you ask, what if we also require that the Pontryagin classes are (finitely) invertible?  There's probably a counterexample here too, though I don't have one at hand.

**Added later.** Here's one. (I hope: I keep needing to fix it.)  If $G$ is a finite *$p$-group*, then the "Borel construction" defines a bijection between of: the set $\mathrm{Rep}_n(G)$ of isomorphism classes of real $n$-dimensional representations of $G$ into the set $\mathrm{Bun}_n(G)$ of isomorphism classes of real $n$-dimensional vector bundles over the classifying space $BG$.  In representation theory, there are no additive inverses, so non-trivial bundles over $BG$ which come from representations cannot have inverses. So it's enough to find a non-trivial representation $V$ whose characteristic classes all vanish.

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $p^2$, where $p$ is an odd prime, generated by an element $\sigma$.  Let $L$ be the $1$-dimensional complex representation given by $\sigma|L=e^{2\pi i/p}$, and write $V$ for the *real* $2$-dimensional vector bundle underlying the complex line bundle $EG\times_G L\to BG$.  It appears that the Pontryagin classes vanish: up to signs, the total Pontryagin class is the total Chern class of $V\otimes \mathbb{C}\approx L\oplus \overline{L}$, and we compute $c(V)=c(L)c(\overline{L}) = (1+px)(1-px) = 1-p^2x^2 = 0$.

(The fact about the bijection $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ into $\mathrm{Bun}(G)$ is non-trivial; it follows from a theorem of Dwyer and Zabrodsky ("Maps between classifying spaces", LNM 1298).  I don't know a more elementary proof, but a condition such as "$G$ is a $p$-group" is probably necessary.)

**End addition.**

There are obstructions in $K$-theory to "inverting" bundles.  There are exterior power operators $\lambda^k:KO(X)\to KO(X)$, such that if $[V]$ is the $K$-class of an actual bundle $V$, we have $\lambda^k([V])=[\Lambda^k V]$, the class of the exterior power bundle.  The formal sum $\Lambda_t(x)\in KO(X)[[t]]$ given by 
$$
\Lambda_t(x)= 1+\lambda^1(x)t+\lambda^2(x)t^2+\dots
$$
has a Whitney formula ($\Lambda_t(x+y)=\Lambda_t(x)\Lambda_t(y)$), coming from the usual decomposition $\Lambda^nV=\sum \Lambda^iV\otimes \Lambda^{n-i}V$.  Furthermore, if $x=[V]$ is the class of an honest $n$-dimensional bundle, we must have $\lambda^i([V])=[\Lambda^iV]=0$ for $i>n$, so that $\Lambda_t(x)$ is polynomial.

In this case, trivial bundles don't have trivial $\Lambda$-class; instead, writing "$n$" for the trivial $n$-plane bundle, we have $\Lambda_t(n)=(1+t)^n$.  Thus, an isomorphism $V\oplus W= n$ implies an identity $\Lambda_t([V])\Lambda_t([W])=(1+t)^n$.

So an even stronger form of your question is: if $V$ is a vector bundle (over a nice space) such that $\Lambda_t([V])/(1+t)^n \in KO(X)[[t]]$ is a polynomial, must it follow that there exists a bundle $W$ such that $V\oplus W\approx n$?  Again, I don't have a counterexample here.

Comment: I've added to my answer, giving a counterexample to the Pontryagin class version of the statement.

Comment: Wow! Not only is your answer great but it improves from minute to minute! It will take me a little time to digest, since I didn't know this method of using representation theory, but I have a fantastic teacher now...Thanks again, Charles.

Comment: Well, I keep removing errors each time too.  The claim that "bundles over BG" are the same as G-representations is too strong; it's not true, as was already known to Atiyah in 1961.  

Comment: You say «so non-trivial bundles over BG which come from representations cannot have inverses»: couldn't the inverse *not* come from a representation?

Comment: @Mariano: good point.  I've fixed the answer to address it.

Comment: Here's a more direct proof of what I need.  Claim: If $V$ and $W$ are real vector bundles over $BG$ of dimensions $m$ and $n$ (with $G$ any finite group), then $V\oplus W$ trivial implies $V$ trivial.  Proof: a trivialization of $V\oplus W$ gives a map $BG\to G(m+n,m)$, where $G(m+n,m)$ is the Grassmannian of $m$-planes in $R^{m+n}$.  By Miller's theorem (aka the Sullivan conjecture), any map from $BG$ to a finite CW complex (such as the Grassmannian) is homotopic to a constant map.  Thus $V$ and $W$ are equivalent to trivial bundles.